# Poll an Android Gamepad?

Tags: android, gamepad

Is there any way to access the values from a gamepad without using the `onKey` or `onGenericMotion` listener methods?

I want to be able to poll the gamepad values at a fixed rate, but I can't see any way to directly access the device.  The `InputDevice` class only lets you grab the connected devices, but once you have one there doesn't seem to be a way of reading values at arbitrary times.

Comment: If you using a specific gamepad you can lok forward for a stream protocol to read the values, else, you can use the events and set state inside the app and read the state instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "Stream protocol".  And using the events is part of the problem, I don't appear to be getting the keyup events, so if I'm trying to trigger along press I can't tell when it's finished.

Comment: I mean, some way to connect it and read events or receive events as a stream

Comment: Ok, well that's what the `onKey` and `onMotion` events do, but the up events are not coming through, making key hold events impossible to detect.  Also the buttons repeat like a keyboard, you get an event, then a pause, then a load more events at the keyboard repeat rate.  I need a faster rate without the pause.

Comment: You can ignore keyrepeat events by checking for event.getRepeatCount() == 0. Android gamepad support relies on the underlying Linux APIs, so one option would be to add some native code to collect the gamepad events at that level (joydev, evdev, or even hidraw). I think onKeyUp should work for gamepad buttons, can you share your code so we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: I found a schoolboy error regarding the keyUp events in that I was not passing them along to be processed, only the keyDown.

Comment: Regarding my other problem of querying the pad state at faster intervals than the key repeat event, I've set up a timer and query state that I save when the events do change, this way I can constantly broadcast the joystick position even when it's not been moved for a while.

I started looking at getting the pad data with native, but didn't quite get it working before I found my stupid keyUp mistake.  I'm quite surprised this ability is only available to native.